# Conversion failed when converting date or time from character string error?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

i have a problem with this error i don't know why but i try many thing and search about it bout i didn't find any thing to solve this problem ( i want to make a query to calculate the age for the client auto in a column i have the Civil number for him like (286063001795) and i have some wrong civil No in my data ) the query is working good with little of data when i use it with my table gave me that error

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tabl]
set dob = CONVERT(date, convert(varchar(10), 17000000 + (CIVILIDD / 100000)))

select *, datediff(Month, dob, getdate())/12 as age, (CIVILIDD / 100000),17000000 + (CIVILIDD / 100000)
from [tabl]
```

> Name_Arabic   nvarchar(255)   Checked
>   CIVILIDD    bigint  Checked
>   gender  nvarchar(255)   Checked
>   NATIONALITY nvarchar(255)   Checked
>   dob date    Checked

Comment: Starting with sql server 2012, there is  `TRY_CONVERT` (also TRY_CAST, TRY_PARSE) - it tries to convert to a specific data type , and in case of error it return `NULL` . Add this function in your dataset and then search for  `NULL`   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @SabinBio set dob = TRY_CONVERT(date, convert(varchar(10), 17000000 + (CIVILIDD / 100000))) is that what you mean

Comment: @SabinBio how is that i have more than million record

Comment: If you have more than million records (no where clause in your update query), it's a good practice to do your update in a batch mode , see here :  http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/   - here it's for delete ; the same could be for update

Comment: To identify just the bad rows use `WHERE dob IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(date, <expression>) IS NULL;`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
set dob = TRY_CONVERT(date, convert(varchar(10), 17000000 + (CIVILIDD / 100000)))
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, can you offer an edit that shows a little more context of what's going on here to help future internet visitors? https://xkcd.com/979/